# "Unanswered" questions are answered

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

When you go to the "Unanswered" tab and go to the last page using the navigation buttons at the bottom, all of the questions are answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not actually a bug. Despite the name, the unanswered tab will have all questions that either don't have answers at all or have un-upvoted answers.

So if a question has one or more answers and their score is 0, it will be considered *unanswered* since theoretically they have yet to be evaluated.

Comment: But all of the questions visible in this way have accepted answers.  Shouldn't they be invisible in this view?

Comment: @APerson241 On what site is that happening? I tried SO but it seems to be working fine.